# Timing touches on an iPad

Tags: ipad

I've been looking to try and measure the time between touch events (looking at the UITouch class). On the UITouch class there is the timeStamp property that gives this time but it is in seconds.

For the application I am looking at I would like to be able to measure in milliseconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just multiply the `timestamp` by 1000 and you have milliseconds. The `timestamp` property is defined as `NSTimeInterval` which is actually a typedef for `double`.

Comment: Do you know the likely precision I could expect? I'm not going to see just round numbers. Is it a reasonable expectation to (if the user is quick enough) to get a time in the 5-10ms?

Comment: Depends on how fast you process the touches and other things like rendering... I'd suggest to just try it out. 5-10ms would be faster than the screen refresh rate though, so the resolution will likely be a bit lower than that.